# Maven не хочет SQLite драйвер подгружать

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, sqlite3

[image: Вот собственно что выдает]

Не видит драйвер. При запуске через идею все замечательно работает.
В зависимостях прописал драйвер. Прикрепил хмl'ку
Что не так то?

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.irens.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте плагин для сборки с зависимостями. Думаю в итоговом jar их сейчас нет. Можете для начала проверить. Если нет Добавьте этот плагин. Он забиндин на package, так что собираете так же и проверяйте

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass> <!-- тут свой main class вставьте -->
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> 
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Я сейчас как бабушки наговорить хочу "Счастья Вам" и т.д.)
Огромное спасибо

Comment: @ДмитрийСаевский для этого можете проголосовать за ответ и пометить его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще один вариант. Так как вы используете maven, будет лучше запустить программу им же:

```
C:\Users\dimas\IdeaProjects\irens> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.irens.Main
```