# Создание jar файла для запуска программы работающей с БД

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, build

#### Имеется :

Консольная программа, к ней подключена вложенная БД.
В IDEA всё работает отлично.

#### Требуется :

Создать работающий корректно запускаемый jar.

Когда запускаю созданный jar, выдаёт

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

#### Сам вопрос:

Где и что надо указать, чтобы созданный jar сам подгружал недостающий драйвер(а я так понимаю, что это именно драйвера не хватает)  и работал на разных машинах ?
В крайнем случае, посоветуйте, в какую сторону гуглить.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того как вы собираете. Вижу несколько возможных проблем:

1. В вашем **jar** отсутствуют сторонние библиотеки. В таком случае нужно добавить их в исходный артифакт. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746236/10353) написано как это сделать
2. Просто не загружен класс драйвера **jdbc**. Его нужно явно проинициализировать через `Class.forName("ru.izebit.MySuperJdbcDriver")`

Answer (score 0):

Создать файл `MANIFEST.MF` и добавить его в jar файл в папку `META-INF`, и в нем указать свойство:

```
Class-Path: недостающий-драйвер.jar
```

Более подробно про добавление классов в jar файл можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

> Возможно, вам придется ссылаться на классы в других JAR-файлах из
> JAR-файла.
>
> Например, в типичной ситуации приложение поставляется в JAR-файле, чей
> манифест ссылается на другой JAR-файл (или несколько разных
> JAR-файлов), который служит в качестве утилит для целей этого приложения.
>
> Вы указываете классы для включения в поле заголовка `Class-Path` в файле
> манифеста апплета или приложения. Заголовок `Class-Path` принимает
> следующий вид:
>
> ```
> Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name имя_каталога / jar3-name
> ```
>
> Используя заголовок `Class-Path` в манифесте, вы можете не указывать
> длинное `-classpath` при вызове Java для запуска вашего приложения.

---

В IDEA вам нужно создать jar-артифакт если вы собираетесь собирать jar файл вручную. Вот примерно то, что нужно учитывать при создании такого артифакта:

> Чтобы создать файл `.jar`, вам необходимо создать артефакт. Артефакт -
> это содержимое архива. Существуют предопределенные шаблоны для
> создания архивов `.jar`, `.war`, `.ear`. Вы можете выбрать проект для
> создания артефакта проекта. По умолчанию он определен пустым, и вам
> нужно определить содержимое артефакта. Вы можете перетащить
> скомпилированный вывод на него, но не делать этого с библиотечными
> архивами. Поскольку библиотеки в этом случае будут упакованы внутри
> файла `.jar`, вам потребуется создать отдельный загрузчик классов для их
> загрузки до запуска приложения. Вместо этого вы изменяете тип
> артефакта на **Другое** и перетаскиваете `.jar` и зависимые библиотеки в
> выходной корень. Таким образом библиотечные архивы будут скопированы
> вместе с созданным `.jar`. Вам также необходимо создать `MANIFEST.MF` и
> указать `Class-Path` для зависимых библиотек. Все файлы будут сохранены
> в каталоге, который вы указали для создания артефакта. Вы можете
> создать его, используя меню **Построить артефакт**.